# Appending ascending images based on the id of parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, append

Say I had the following three divs with unique ids on a page

```
<div id="product-id-001"></div>
<div id="product-id-002"></div>
<div id="product-id-003"></div>
```

What code would I need to add the following image elements based on the id of the div?

```
<div id="product-id-001">

    <img src="images/product-id-001-1.jpg"></img>
    <img src="images/product-id-001-2.jpg"></img>
    <img src="images/product-id-001-3.jpg"></img>

</div>

<div id="product-id-002">

    <img src="images/product-id-002-1.jpg"></img>
    <img src="images/product-id-002-2.jpg"></img>
    <img src="images/product-id-002-3.jpg"></img>

</div>

<div id="product-id-003">

    <img src="images/product-id-003-1.jpg"></img>
    <img src="images/product-id-003-2.jpg"></img>
    <img src="images/product-id-003-3.jpg"></img>

</div>
```

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div[id^=product]').each(function(index, elem) {
   for(var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
       $('<img>', {
          src:    '/images/' + elem.id + i
       }).appendTo(this);
   }
});
```

**Demo**: http://www.jsfiddle.net/9S9Av/

(You need Firebug or another DOM inspector to see the result)

Comment: Gosh that is beautiful! What is your paypal address?

Comment: @user427687: andreas.goebel@typeofnan.com :o)

Answer (score 0):

From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

> "The .append() method inserts the specified content as the last child of each element in the jQuery collection"

So:

```
$('#product-id-001").append('<img src="images/product-id-001-1.jpg"></img>');
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
// Select all elements with an id beginning with product-id:
var $productContainers = $('[id^=product-id]');
// Loop through the matched elements and append the images:
$productContainers.each(function () {
   var $this = $(this),
       productId = $this.attr('id'),
       numImages = 3,
       extension = '.jpg';
   // Create and append the images based on the configuration above. Note that this
   // assumes that each product have three valid images.
   for (var i = 1; i <= numImages; i++)
   {
     var $image = $('<img alt="" />').attr('src', 'images/'+productId+'-'+i+extension);
     $image.appendTo($this);
   }
});
```

Comment: This won't work. You need to replace `$this.val('id')` by `this.id` or `$this.attr('id')` and you need to replace `.val('src')` with `.attr('src')`

Comment: Thanks. Just wrote it up in a hurry.